# losing serial data while transferring with high baud rate

Tags: visual-c++, .net-3.5

The baud rate is 115200 in receiver, transmitter side, and the transmitter sends about 300 bytes per second. Although the data velocity is low, after a while, data is lost.

All serial configs in both sides are equal (baud rate, stop bit, parity, data bits).

Another problem is about handshaking. Both devices support handshaking & flow control, but
in our application we are not allowed to use flow control because we can use only the Tx, RX pins to make a communication. We can not use any flow control such as hardware or software.

Another problem is that the Microsoft samples are too difficult to understand and use.

We will be thankful if anyone has a suggestion or a good idea or any related experience.